# App for Blocking Website in Safari (For Productivity Purposes)

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions, productivity

Are there any apps on OS X that can block certain websites ('time-wasting ones') for a certain interval?

Preferably works for Safari.

Comment: It seems like all the options in 2019 / 2020 are paid for services :-( very disappointing when this is possible on Windows and Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com) is a free app that will let you enter the websites you want blocked and for how long you want them blocked for.

Comment: You cannot block facebook.com and allow Whatsapp....really annoying!

Comment: insane find! worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

[WasteNoTime](http://www.bumblebeesystems.com/) is a good app for this. It is a browser extension.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Safari 11.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying Mindful Browsing and I really like it. It's very simple to setup and does the job perfectly.

Check out the website: http://www.mindfulbrowsing.com.

Comment: It doesn't seem to exist on Safari extensions anymore

Answer (score 1):

Cold Turkey seems to work quite well and is free (although you have to pay if you want the schedule functionality)

Answer (score 0):

I downloades SelfControl, and while it seems the only option for Safari users, it is a very limited program. You can only block up to 1 day. Unlike programs like stayfocusd, and cold turkey, which allow you to properly schedule blocking times, I might advise you to just switch to using chrome again, there seem to be more well developed programs for that, unfortunately

Comment: you say 'just switch to chrome' but it doesn't stop you from 'just switching to Safari again' when you want to look at facebook

Comment: You can extend block timer for longer block durations

Answer (score 0):

Blocker for Facebook is available for Safari: https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.devankuleindiren.blockerforfacebook-ZRQ35C78DB

It creates a button that, upon clicking, asks you for how many minutes you'd like to block Facebook. If you go to Facebook, it throws a popup stating Facebook is blocked and redirects you to Google.

Comment: These seems to be a dead link now

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to try this but you could try removing Safari completely and use Leechblock for Firefox & Chrome

[Mac Mojave, how to remove Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356611/mac-mojave-how-to-remove-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Focus is a Website and application blocker for macOS https://heyfocus.com